# Module id is removed from angular 2? I have tried with moduleId:module.id working for me but in angular2.0

Tags: angular

I have tried with `moduleId:module.id` working for me, but in angular4.o is module id has to write in component or not?
Module id is removed from angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes no need to manually write module id in angular 4.0 
angular can take of the path reference u should provide relative path is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 4 removed the module.id , you only write component-relative paths.

You can check [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html)